# Using asInstanceOf on Generic Types in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless

Say, I have a class like this:

```
class Funky[A, B](val foo: A, val bar: B) {
  override def toString: String = s"Funky($foo, $bar)"
}
```

With some method that looks like this:

```
def cast(t: Any): Option[Funky[A, B]] = {
  if (t == null) None
  else if (t.isInstanceOf[Funky[_, _]]) {
    val o = t.asInstanceOf[Funky[_, _]]
    for {
      _ <- typA.cast(o.foo)
      _ <- typB.cast(o.bar)
    } yield o.asInstanceOf[Funky[A, B]]
  } else None
}
```

How does the isInstanceOf and asInstanceOf work? The Runtime has no information on the actual types that are contained in Funky. So how is this code working? Any clues?

Comment: Did you look at the source code for `asInstanceOf` operator?

Comment: @BobDalgleish At least here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library-aux/scala/Any.scala you don't see much. Most "interesting" methods are implemented as `sys.error("<an incomprehensible message of an error so horrible that no user should ever see it>")`. The class is so fundamental, that the bytecode is not compiled from any source, but instead directly generated by the compiler. The source code is there mostly to generate ScalaDoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just take it apart.

Suppose that you somehow obtain instances `typA: Typable[A]` and `typB: Typable[B]`, so that `typA` has a method

```
def cast(a: Any): Option[A] = ...
```

and similarly for `typB`. The `cast` method is expected to return `Some[A]` if the argument is indeed of type `A`, and `None` otherwise. These instances can obviously be constructed for primitive types `Int` and `String` (they are already provided by the library).

Now you want to use `typA` and `typB` to implement `cast` for `Funky[A, B]`.

The `null` check should be clear, you can perform it on anything. But then comes the first `isInstanceOf`:

```
  else if (t.isInstanceOf[Funky[_, _]]) {
```

Note that the type arguments of `Funky` have been replaced by underscores. This is because *the generic parameters* of `Funky` are erased, and not available at runtime. However, we still can differentiate between `Funky[_, _]` and, for example, `Map[_, _]`, because the parameterized type itself is preserved, even though the parameters are erased. Moreover, `isInstanceOf` could even differentiate between a `TreeMap` and a `HashMap`, even if both instances had compile-time type `Map`: the runtime type is available, it's only the generic parameters that are forgotten.

Similarly, once you know that `t` is of type `Funky`, you can cast it into
`Funky[_, _]`,

```
    val o = t.asInstanceOf[Funky[_, _]]
```

replacing the generic parameters by existential types. This means: you know only that there are *some* types `X` and `Y` such that `o` is of type `Funky[X, Y]`, but you don't know what those `X` and `Y` are. However, now you at least know that `o` has methods `foo` and `bar` (even though you don't know what their return types are).

But now you can take `o.foo` and `o.bar` and feed them into the `typA.cast` and `typeB.cast`. The underscores on the left hand side of the monadic bind mean that you discard the instances of type `A` and `B`, which are returned wrapped in `Some`. You only care that both casts don't return a `None`:

```
    for {
      _ <- typA.cast(o.foo)
      _ <- typB.cast(o.bar)
    } yield /* ... */
```

If one of the casts failed and returned a `None`, the entire monadic expression would evaluate to `None`, and so the method would return `None`, signifying that the overall cast into `Funky[A, B]` has failed.
If both casts succeed, then we know that `o` is indeed of type `Funky[A, B]`, so we can cast `o` into `Funky[A, B]`:

```
o.asInstanceOf[Funky[A, B]]
```

You might wonder "how is this possible, we don't know anything about `A` and `B` at runtime!", but this is ok, because this `asInstanceOf` is there only to satisfy the type-checking stage of the compiler. It *cannot do anything at runtime*, because it can only check the `Funky` part, but not the erased parameters `A` and `B`.

Here is a shorter illustration of the phenomenon:

```
val m: Map[Long, Double] = Map(2L -> 100d)
val what = m.asInstanceOf[Map[Int, String]]
println("It compiles, and the program does not throw any exceptions!")
```

Just save it as a script and feed it to the `scala` interpreter. It will compile and run without complaints, because the `asInstanceOf` is blind for anything beyond `Map`. So, the second `asInstanceOf` is there only to persuade the type-checker that the returned value is indeed of the type `Funky[A, B]`, and it is the responsibility of the programmer not to make any nonsensical claims.

To summarize: `isInstanceOf` is the thing that does something at runtime (it checks that instances conform to some concrete type, and returns runtime-values `true`-`false`). The `asInstanceOf` has two different functions. The first one (which casts to a concrete class `Funky[_, _]`) has a side effect at runtime (the cast can fail and throw an exception). The second one (`asInstanceOf[Funky[A, B]]`) is there only to satisfy the type-checking phase at compile time.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the elements are *specific* types, with something like:

```
Funky(1, 2).foo.isInstanceOf[String] // false
Funky(1, 2).foo.isInstanceOf[Int] // true
```

But if you try to check for a *generic* type it will not work. For example:

```
def check[A](x: Any) = x.isInstanceOf[A]
check[String](1) // true
check[String](Funky(1, 2).foo) // true
```

And the compiler gives you a warning message that explains the error:

> abstract type A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

However, the code you showed seems to be working around this by some other method here:

```
_ <- typA.cast(o.foo)
_ <- typB.cast(o.bar)
```

Without seeing the implementation of those objects, my guess is they have some sort of `TypeTag` or `ClassTag` and use that. That is almost always the recommended way to work around erasure.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say! I was wondering how the compiler would interpret a generic asInstanceOf? I have given the cast method that was missing!

Comment: ok I tried to edit and answer a bit more. Thanks for including more of the method, but it's still calling out to some `typA.cast` method that seems crucial

Comment: @JoeK My guess is that those things are instances of the Typeable typeclass flying around... https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala